# repeating print every 10 minutes in illustrator

Tags: jsx, adobe-illustrator

I have some small printers which need to print every 10 or 15 minutes to decrease damage of printers.
so, I need a script (jsx or vbs) to send a command to illustrator to print every 10 minutes. Is that possible?
If so, How?

I tried some basic js codes but some functions doesnot work

```
// Set the time interval in milliseconds
var interval = 600000;

// Define the function to print the document
function printDocument() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    doc.print(false, false, null);
}

// Call the function at the specified interval
while (true) {
    printDocument();
    app.sleep(interval);
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details about those printers (make, model), and who told you to print every 10 or 15 minutes?  (Is it the person who is selling toner-supplies (or ink) to you ?)

Comment: Please do not use vague remarks in your question like: "but some functions doesnot work"  Simply provide the errors message and the line in the code where this is happening.

Comment: print function and sleep doesnot work

Comment: I never used `doc.print()` method and I can't test it right now (I have no printer at the hand). Theoretically your code looks correct and should work. Except the `sleep()` method belongs to the object `$`, not to `app`. So it should be: `$.sleep(interval)`.

Comment: And I'd try `doc.print();` without arguments. It's likely there should be an instance of the object  `PrintOptions`. Something like: `var opts = new PrintOptions(); doc.print(opts);` See the example here: https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/PrintOptions.html#jsobjref-printoptions the preferences depend on your real printer, but perhaps the default options will work fine for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works by $ for both "print" and "sleep", But there is other problem. When I Use "sleep", I could not use Illustrator. It goes to "Not responding". Scripts works and every 10 minutes send the prints but Illustrator is on "Not responding".

Comment: Of course. Illustrator runs the script. Unless you stop the script somehow you can't use Illustrator. If you need Illustrator on this computer you need another approach. I believe it can be done with a similar script for Bridge, Acrobat, Photoshop, InDesign, etc. You can try to run this script (exactly as it is) in InDesign. It has the same methods `doc.print()` and `$.sleep()`

Comment: For InDesign, I guess, it might be `doc.print(false)` to prevent the Print dialog window. Not sure. Just a guess.